Struts 6.3 <s:script> tag removes id attribute
We are using Struts version 6.3.0.2. A third party JavaScript that we are using, needs an id property to be set in the script declaration.
The following code is used:
<s:script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/Third-Party-Min.js?param1=Value1&param2=value2" id="unique_id" />
In the generated HTML code, the id gets removed. This is how it looks:
<script async type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/Third-Party-Min.js?param1=value1&param2=value2" nonce="Th7ugNVKpxxMfb5CfK7gc9Dr" />
Since the Script expects the id and throws an exception. If we don't use <s:script> tag, the nonce value does not get generated and browser complains about content security policy violation. How to achieve id property inclusion with <s:script> tag?
